# No work being assigned in office

Tags: colleagues

I know that similar kind of questions have already been answered before, but I have a slightly different situation and would appreciate a suggestion. Pardon me for the lengthiness.

I am a Software Engineer in an IT company and have been working for 2.5 years here now, my performance has been good through out. I joined this project in August 2014(my second project in this company) and have only worked on 1 assignment since then, that too for 1.5 months, before which I was kind of involved in some other work on defects just for name sake as it was handled by my senior teammate. Now when i am done with my assignment, my manager asked me to work on the same defects that i was doing before with the help of my senior as I have very less knowledge on that and he would train me.
Now, from past one month I am daily asking my senior about the work to be done, but he was ignoring me and i was fed up sitting idle the whole day.
My manager himself asked me once that why i have not been given anything to work and talked to my senior to assign me work on daily basis.
There is one more lady working with us and they both belong to same place, so if they are working on something, they won't involve me and discuss things in their language, i know this as i sit just beside my senior.

I finally spoke to my manager about this after 3 days, i.e, the colleague is ignoring me and they both won't involve me in anything and i can't sit idle the whole day. Manager responded positively saying that there is a lot of work and he'll talk to my senior and he did. He asked me to immediately inform him if this repeats(he sits behind us).Due to that we are even going to have daily status calls with our onshore manager.
But my senior has still not started with the knowledge transfer and from 2 days they both again sit together and discuss things in their language (be it just for atmost 1 hr), I myself peek into his system and ask things and he answers me very briefly or sometimes he just keeps mum. Rest of the time he is just roaming around, even if i asked him 2 days ago to explain me the work.
I can't start working on things myself, I need his help to understand the system.
Please advise what should i do in this situation, i am really tired of this and don't think that it's good to bug my manager again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make this a "us vs them" kind of situation. It can be frustrating for both sides.

When you don't understand something ask. Most people will explain things when asked.

Actively look for opportunities to contribute / learn and show them you can get work done.

If you are not given anything to do, attempt to talk about what the senior developer is doing / working  on. Remember not to turn this into a confrontation and do your best to come up to speed.

Couple of clarifications:

When you say "their language" are they speaking a different language or the terms they are using are unknown to you?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, and believe me I am a calm  person and don't get much into confrontations. I have already asked him to explain the work i have to do, and his response was even he is not clear on those, although i keep on asking him whatever i have doubts on. Anyways he says that we will start working from Monday(when the daily status call starts). Their language I mean a different regional language that i don't understand.

Comment: keep calm and have a professional attitude. do your best.  when you've done that there is basically nothing more you can do.